# Why the content of file is not send?

Tags: c, sockets, networking, client-server

I tried to implement a client and server in C using TCP/IP for send message and file using sockets. The message is send but content of file not working. I want to send a file from server to client, in client the file was created but the content of file from server It is not transmitted to the client. 
In client waiting the message, if message contain "GET_FILE a.txt" the server sent the file a.txt to client if you enter other text this is a simple message. 
So, if you run the client and type the message "GET_FILE nameOfFile" server need to return this file, and if you type the other message server need to return message tasted.

This is my server code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>    //strlen
#include <stdlib.h>    //strlen
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h> //inet_addr
#include <unistd.h>    //write
#include <pthread.h> //for threading , link with lpthread

//the thread function
void *connection_handler(void *);
void *SendFileToClient(int*);

pthread_t tid;

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int socket_desc , client_sock , c , *new_sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server , client;

    //Create socket
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }
    puts("Socket created");

    //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons( 8888 );

   // printf("!!!!!!!%s", server.sin_addr.s_addr);

    //Bind
    if( bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        //print the error message
        perror("bind failed. Error");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("bind done");

    //Listen
    listen(socket_desc , 3);

    //Accept and incoming connection
    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);


    //Accept and incoming connection
    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    while( (client_sock = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c)) )
    {
        puts("Connection accepted");

        pthread_t sniffer_thread;
        new_sock = malloc(1);
        *new_sock = client_sock;

        if( pthread_create( &sniffer_thread , NULL ,  connection_handler , (void*) new_sock) < 0)
        {
            perror("could not create thread");
            return 1;
        }

        //Now join the thread , so that we dont terminate before the thread
        //pthread_join( sniffer_thread , NULL);
        puts("Handler assigned");
    }

    if (client_sock < 0)
    {
        perror("accept failed");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

/*
 * This will handle connection for each client
 * */
void *connection_handler(void *socket_desc)
{
    //Get the socket descriptor
    int sock = *(int*)socket_desc;
    int read_size;
    int err;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    char *message , client_message[2000], file_name[2000];


    //Receive a message from client
    while( (read_size = recv(sock , client_message , 2000 , 0)) > 0 )
    {
        //Send the message back to client
        if(strncmp(client_message, "GET_FILE ", 8) == 0)
        {
            for(i = 9; i < strlen(client_message); i++){
                file_name[j] = client_message[i];
                j++;
            }

            err = pthread_create(&tid, NULL, &SendFileToClient, &file_name);
            if (err != 0)
                printf("\ncan't create thread :[%s]", strerror(err));


        }
        else
        {
            write(sock , client_message , strlen(client_message));
        }
    }

    if(read_size == 0)
    {
        puts("Client disconnected");
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    else if(read_size == -1)
    {
        perror("recv failed");
    }

    //Free the socket pointer
    free(socket_desc);

    return 0;
}


void* SendFileToClient(int* file_name){
            int connfd = (int)*file_name;
            printf("Connection accepted and id: %d\n",connfd);
            printf("Connected to Client: %s:%d\n", "127.0.0.1", 8888);
            //write(connfd, file_name,256);

            FILE *fp = fopen(file_name,"rb");

            if(fp==NULL)
            {
                printf("File opern error");
                return 1;   
            }   

            /* Read data from file and send it */
            while(1)
            {
                /* First read file in chunks of 256 bytes */
                unsigned char buff[1024] = {0};
                int nread = fread(buff, 1, 1024, fp);
                //printf("Bytes read %d \n", nread);        

                /* If read was success, send data. */
                if(nread > 0)
                {
                    //printf("Sending \n");
                    write(connfd, buff, nread);
                }

                if (nread < 1024)
                {
                    if (feof(fp))
                    {
                        printf("End of file\n");
                        printf("File transfer completed for id: %d\n", connfd);
                    }

                    if (ferror(fp)){
                        printf("Error reading\n");
                        break;
                    }
                }

                printf("Closing Connection for id: %d\n", connfd);
                close(connfd);
                shutdown(connfd, SHUT_WR);
                sleep(2);
            }
}
```

This is the client code:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h> //printf
#include <string.h>    //strlen
#include <sys/socket.h>    //socket
#include <arpa/inet.h> //inet_addr

void gotoxy(int x,int y)
{
    printf("%c[%d;%df",0x1B,y,x);
}


int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    char message[1000] , server_reply[2000];

    //Create socket
    sock = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (sock == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }
    puts("Socket created");

    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons( 8888 );

    //Connect to remote server
    if (connect(sock , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        perror("connect failed. Error");
        return 1;
    }

    puts("Connected\n");

    //keep communicating with server
    while(1)
    {

        char file_name[2000];
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        printf("Enter message : ");
        //scanf("%s" , message);
        gets(message);
        //puts(message);
        //printf("%d", strncmp(message, "GET_FILE ", 9) );

        if(strncmp(message, "GET_FILE ", 8) == 0)
        {

            //Send some data
            if( send(sock , message , strlen(message) , 0) < 0)
            {
                puts("Send failed");
                return 1;
            }

            for(i = 9; i < strlen(message); i++){
                file_name[j] = message[i];
                j++;
            }

            /* Create file where data will be stored */
            FILE *fp;
            int bytesReceived = 0;
            char recvBuff[1024];
            puts(file_name);
            puts("Receiving file...");
            fp = fopen(file_name, "ab"); 
            if(NULL == fp)
            {
                printf("Error opening file");
                return 1;
            }

            long double sz = 1;

            /* Receive data in chunks of 256 bytes */
            while((bytesReceived = read(sock, recvBuff, 1024)) > 0)
            { 
                printf("%d", bytesReceived);
                sz++;
                gotoxy(0,4);
                //printf("Received: %lf Mb",(sz/1024));
                fflush(stdout);
                // recvBuff[n] = 0;
                fwrite(recvBuff, 1, bytesReceived, fp);
                // printf("%s \n", recvBuff);
            }

            if(bytesReceived < 0)
            {
                printf("\n Read Error \n");
            }
            printf("\nFile OK....Completed\n");
        }
        else
        {
            //Send some data
            if( send(sock , message , strlen(message) , 0) < 0)
            {
                puts("Send failed");
                return 1;
            }
            //Receive a reply from the server
            if( recv(sock , server_reply , 2000 , 0) < 0)
            {
                puts("recv failed");
                break;
            }

            puts("Server reply :");
            puts(server_reply);
        }
    }

    close(sock);
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you very much for your help!

**UPDATE!!!**

I updated the code for server, but now I have a error message from server: "
Error reading
recv failed: Bad file descriptor
"

The client code it's the same, the server code now is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>    //strlen
#include <stdlib.h>    //strlen
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h> //inet_addr
#include <unistd.h>    //write
#include <pthread.h> //for threading , link with lpthread

//the thread function
void *connection_handler(void *);
pthread_t tid;

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int socket_desc , client_sock , c , *new_sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server , client;

    //Create socket
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }
    puts("Socket created");

    //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons( 8888 );

   // printf("!!!!!!!%s", server.sin_addr.s_addr);

    //Bind
    if( bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        //print the error message
        perror("bind failed. Error");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("bind done");

    //Listen
    listen(socket_desc , 3);

    //Accept and incoming connection
    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);


    //Accept and incoming connection
    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    while( (client_sock = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c)) )
    {
        puts("Connection accepted");

        pthread_t sniffer_thread;
        new_sock = malloc(1);
        *new_sock = client_sock;

        if( pthread_create( &sniffer_thread , NULL ,  connection_handler , (void*) new_sock) < 0)
        {
            perror("could not create thread");
            return 1;
        }

        //Now join the thread , so that we dont terminate before the thread
        //pthread_join( sniffer_thread , NULL);
        puts("Handler assigned");
    }

    if (client_sock < 0)
    {
        perror("accept failed");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

/*
 * This will handle connection for each client
 * */
void *connection_handler(void *socket_desc)
{
    //Get the socket descriptor
    int sock = *(int*)socket_desc;
    int connfd = 0;
    int read_size;
    int err;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    char *message , client_message[2000], file_name[2000];


    //Receive a message from client
    while( (read_size = recv(sock , client_message , 2000 , 0)) > 0 )
    {
        //Send the message back to client
        if(strncmp(client_message, "GET_FILE ", 8) == 0)
        {
            for(i = 9; i < strlen(client_message); i++){
                file_name[j] = client_message[i];
                j++;
            }

            printf("Connection accepted and id: %d\n", sock);
            printf("Connected to Client: %s:%d\n", "127.0.0.1", 8888);

            FILE *fp = fopen(file_name,"rb");

            if(fp==NULL)
            {
                printf("File opern error");
                return 1;   
            }   

            /* Read data from file and send it */
            while(1)
            {
                /* First read file in chunks of 256 bytes */
                unsigned char buff[1024] = {0};
                int nread = fread(buff, 1, 1024, fp);
                //printf("Bytes read %d \n", nread);        

                /* If read was success, send data. */
                if(nread > 0)
                {
                    //printf("Sending \n");
                    write(sock, buff, nread);
                }

                if (nread < 1024)
                {
                    if (feof(fp))
                    {
                        printf("End of file\n");
                        printf("File transfer completed for id: %d\n", sock);
                    }

                    if (ferror(fp)){
                        printf("Error reading\n");
                        break;
                    }
                }
                printf("Closing Connection for id: %d\n", sock);
                close(sock);
                fclose(fp);
                shutdown(sock, SHUT_WR);
            }


        }
        else
        {
            write(sock , client_message , strlen(client_message));
        }
    }

    if(read_size == 0)
    {
        puts("Client disconnected");
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    else if(read_size == -1)
    {
        perror("recv failed");
    }

    //Free the socket pointer
    free(socket_desc);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Client does not close fp after file received.

Comment: What debugging have you done? For example, have you determined whether the problem is in sending the data, receiving the data or writing to file?

Comment: I don't understand: 'int connfd = (int)*file_name;'

Comment: Is 'file_name' NUL terminated, (if so, how/where)?

Comment: 'if( send(sock , message , strlen(message) , 0) < 0)' does not send the NUL terminator

Comment: 'if(strncmp(client_message, "GET_FILE ", 8) == 0)' assumes that a message longer than one byte has been transferred.

Comment: Can you help me now, please ?

Comment: your client code is screwy the `while` loop will not exit because errors are going to be negative.